# Why did composer update everything?

Tags: php, composer-php

I run commands like this a lot to update individual composer packages:

To update package vendor/package-name:

`composer update vendor/package-name`

However, occasionally, composer will ignore my `{vendor/package-name}` and update *everything*. Why would it do that? How can I prevent that from happening?

More details.... "vendor/package" in this case is a private package that I have complete control over, and it has no dependencies. Although, I'd like to be able to safely use composer to update any single package without updating more than needed.

Comment: It sounds like the package you are updating, needs newer versions of other packages that you have installed. Which might need newer versions as well, etc., etc. Do you have a specific example?

Comment: vendor/package-name is a private package with zero dependencies, so the other packages shouldn't be updated, right?

Comment: By the way, you can always check before the actual update using `--dry-run`

Comment: Are you version locking (e.g. no x.x.x`^`) other packages in your composer file?

Comment: @GBWDev In this case, I don't want to version lock my other packages, I still want them to update when I run a general `composer update`. The question here is why do they update when I specify I only want to update package *n*, which has *zero* dependencies? Anyway, this question is a year old, and I haven't had this problem in a while. (Using composer to update a single package is extremely slow, so I built a script to update a specific package and automatically update the composer.lock file. It's more than 10 times faster than vanilla composer, and doesn't have this problem.)